# Attaching files to Azure DevOps work item

Tags: api, azure-devops, attachment

I am trying to attach files (screenshots) to an Azure DevOps work item via a C# desktop app. I have managed to attach files, but they're not valid image files, which leads me to believe that I'm doing something wrong in uploading them.

From the documentation [DevOps Create Attachment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/attachments/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) below is the section on the Request body of the API call, which is rather vague.

[image]

From a [GitHub discussion](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-rest-api-specs/issues/211) this answer seems to suggest that I just upload the binary content directly, which is what I'm doing.

[image]

My code is as follows

```
var img = File.ReadAllBytes(fname);
string query = @"/_apis/wit/attachments?fileName=" + fname + @"&api-version=6.0"
string response = AzureUtils.AttachFile(query, img, "POST", false, "application/octet-stream");
```

Is it correct that I literally pass in the byte array which is read from the file (variable img) as the body?

Why is it not a valid file when I look at it in DevOps?

The code for AttachFile is

```
public static string AttachFile(string query, byte[] data = null, string method = "GET",
    bool dontUseBaseURL = false, string contentType = "application/json-patch+json")
{
    try
    {
      HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(query) as HttpWebRequest;
      request.ContentType = contentType;
      request.Method = method;
      request.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

      request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " +
        Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{1}", ["AzurePAT"]))));

      if (data != null)
      {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
         {
            writer.Write(data);
         }
      }

      HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

      string result = string.Empty;
      using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
      {
         result = reader.ReadToEnd();
      }

      request = null;
      response = null;

       return result;
}
```

Comment: What does AzureUtils.AttachFiles do?

Comment: @TiamoIdzenga I've updated the question with the code for AttachFile. Sorry for the late response, I wasn't notified that there was a question